Can't convince Project Config to make new fields on production
I am trying to troubleshoot a problem with Project Config updates not fully working when applied to my production site.
I am running a simple Git workflow: local Dev site -> git -> live Production site
My deployment process on the production site is to run these commands:
php craft clear-caches/all
git pull https://github.com/username/site.git
composer install --no-interaction
php craft up --interactive=0
php craft clear-caches/all

and finally opening an opcache_reset() page in my browser: https://site.url/opcache_reset.php
Some of my changes do appear in production: I can add UI elements to field layouts, like Horizonal Rule.
But important changes do not show up: I can't get a new field to appear. I can't create a new field group.
If I search for the new fields in the production site's Project Config pages, I see them, but they do not appear as fields in the actual entries.
I've tried clearing caches multiple ways, running 'php craft project-config/apply --force', and rebuilding the entire Project Config. Triple checked my .env and config settings. Nothing has worked and I'm out of ideas. Hoping someone has more suggestions for what I can try next. Thanks.

Do you have any deployment logs? What happens under the hood when the deployment script runs php craft up – do the changes appear to be applied as expected, is there an error, or does Craft simply not pick up on the changes from the YAML file?

Also, if this is OPcache related, ideally you'll want to clear it before craft up, not after. Typically this can be done by reloading the php-fpm service.

I just see craft's usual web.log files and I don't see any thing deployment related. Does craft make deployment logs somewhere else?
I'll move my Opcache step to the initial cache clear, thanks for the tip.

No, Craft knows nothing about your deployment routine; I was thinking more about logs generated in/from the environment or service you're using to deploy. But in terms of Craft logs; you might want to look at the console logs specifically, could be a clue in there.

This is just a guess, but perhaps you have a race condition? Are you certain that the pull has finished by the time craft up starts? I use a similar deployment strategy, but mine is split into two - First I do the pull via the post-update Git hook inside the bare repo, then I do the rest via a post-merge hook in the actual working copy. It's been like 10 years since I set it up so I can't really remember why I'm doing it that way, but it works!

Thanks for the idea. I'm not using hooks, just running the commands line by line using SSH in terminal. The output messages I see don't indicate any problems.
